# Is my answer wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

As their father told them, the elder son took half of the money that was in the box and 200 Dhs.

After that, the junior son came and did the same thing.

Finally, the little son came, did the same thing, and this time there was 200 Dhs left in the box.

How much money there was in the box? And what was the share of each brother?

My answer:

Let x be the initial sum of money that was in the box.

The elder son took: 
$$\dfrac{1}{2}x-200$$
The junior son took:
$$\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{1}{2}x-200)-200$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{4}x-300$$
The little son took:
$$\dfrac{1}{2}(\dfrac{1}{4}x-300)-200$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{8}x-350$$
Since 200 remained in the box, then:
$$\dfrac{1}{8}x-350=200$$
$$\implies x= 4400$$
But my answer is wrong. I don't see that it is.

So, please, I need your assistance. Thank you very much.

Comment: It looks correct.  What answer do you have?

Comment: @ Dr. MV: Thank you very much. The answer I'm given is x=3000

Comment: The oldest son took $\frac{x}{2}+200$.

Comment: That answer is incorrect.  Plug 3000 into the algorithm and watch it fail.  You have the correct answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I believe the OP's expression gives what remains even though it states that which was taken.

Answer (score 4):

As was pointed out by Dr. MV, your analysis and answer are correct. (There are inaccuracies of wording.)  We give an alternate algebra-free solution.

*Work backwards*. Before the littlest guy took the $200$, there was $400$. So before he took the half there was $800$. So before the middle kid took $200$, there was $1000$. So before the middle kid took half there was $2000$. So before the big kid took $200$ there was $2200$. So before he took half there was $4400$.

Comment: Please, forbear with me! what is disturbing me is the approach that forms the solution I'm given: "At first, subtract the remaining, which is 200, and then start computation. Meaning I should start like this: $$(x-200)-\frac{1}{2}(x-200)-200$$

Comment: We can use the "hint" and then argue as in my backwards solution, then add the $200$ at the end. We get $200$, $400$; $600$, $1200$; $1400$, $2800$. Now add the $200$, we get $3000$!  But that is wrong.  At least we have a plausible conjecture about how they got their wrong answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much. If you please, could you turn this comment as an answer, please?

Comment: The "hint" about subtracting the remaining $200$ is not part of your question, it is only mentioned in a comment. And my reconstruction of how they got the wrong answer of $3000$ using the hint is speculative, there may be other ways of using the hint to get $3000$. The important thing is that $4400$ is right, and can be obtained using your analysis or mine.

Comment: @ André Nicolas:Again thank you very much, I really appreciate.

Comment: You are welcome. We could use the hint, but then we would have to add $200+400+800$ to the number obtained.